# MVC URL path extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I was just wondering whether its possible to have something like this: I have an Area named `Admin` and a Controller named 'Edit'. Within this controller I have my Index() which simply lists a bunch of hyperlinks that is treated by the 'Brand' action.

Therefore my url so far is: `Admin/Edit/{Brand}`.

My question is whether it is possible to have for example: `Admin/Edit/{Brand}/Create` (as well as edit and delete). This isn't to delete brands, its just to create things within those brands?

I approach that my approach may be misguided and this may necessitate being split into multiple controllers or whatever so don't think that I would like a workaround to make it work this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define the following route in your area registration:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{brand}/{action}",
    new { action = "Index" }
);
```

And if you wanted to have other controllers than `Edit` in this area which have the default route, you could register 2 routes but you will have to define a constraint for the `{brand}` token or the routing engine won't be able to disambiguate between a brand and a controller action name.

Comment: Its probably worth putting in the answer that this should go underneath my existing `MapRoute` for `Admin/Edit/{brand}`.